# Spring MVC : How to load @PropertySource from WEB-INF

Tags: spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC with java config.

And I have two context configuration classes: `RootContext` and `ServletContext`.

RootContext class is loaded via `<context-param>` in web.xml

Here is the code of RootContext:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import(DaoConfig.class)
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/config/application.properties")
public class RootContext {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }
}
```

If I run the application, I got this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/config/application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Everything works fine if I move `application.properties` file to classpath. But I want it to be in /WEB-INF/config directory.

Any suggestion how to solve this error?

Should I put `@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/config/application.properties")` line to ServletContext instead of RootContext??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a late reply but I hope this may be useful for anyone having the same issue.

You can do this by setting context-param in your web.xml and access it in configuration class with @PropertyResource.

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>myProperties</param-name>
    <param-value>${catalina.home}/conf/application.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**AppConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${myProperties}")
public class AppConfig{

    @Autowired
    Environment env;
```

Comment: Using catalina.home is going to be Tomcat-specific :-(

Comment: Can we use `${catalina.home}` inside `@PropertySource` directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring version 3.2.x, refer to the issue tracker of this issue

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10401

Answer (score 1):

Include the [WebAppRootListener](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/WebAppRootListener.html) in your `web.xml` before your other listeners. It will set a system property `${webapp.root}` with the correct path.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.WebAppRootListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then you can use it as

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${webapp.root}/my.properties")
public class AppConfig{
```

[LogbackConfigListener](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Spring) and [Log4jWebConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html) also do the same thing. What these classes do is implement `ServletContextListener` and grab the path using `servletContext.getRealPath("/")`.

Note, this may not work for Servlet 2.2 containers and Servlet 2.3 ones that do not initialize listeners before servlets.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ResourceLoaders availabe in spring. The one that is propably used by default is the ClassPathResourceLoader, which assumes that the resource can be found somewhere on your classpath (e.g. /WEB-INF/classes)

I'd suggest to either change the resource loader and make it a FileSystemResourceLoader or put your configuration files in a package somewhere in the classpath.

I prefer the later one, as configuration files outside of the classpath are always a mess, when deploying your application.